# how to solve the 1045 error

Tags: phpmyadmin

Steps to reproduce

I run phpMyAdmin on MAMP.
MySQL is running correctly. However it fails to connect MySQL through phpMyAdmin, which shows

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

with the same user (root) and password (poiu) that works well on the MySQL workbench.

```
Operating system:
MacOS 10.12.6
Web server: MAMP
Database: MySQL 5.7.2
PHP version: 7.1.1
phpMyAdmin version: 4.4.4
```

the config.inc.php file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'poiu';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_garbage_threshold'] = 50;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_repository_threshold'] = '32M';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_blob_timeout'] = 600;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_log_threshold'] = '32M';
```

I think the setting of password would be correct. How can I get access into phpMyAdmin?

BTW, the `'auth_type'` is set to `'cookie'`. I tried changing this value but if I did then, it shows also `error 1045` but cannot even get the log in window.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, this is pure admin stuff. Therefore it is off topic here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to set it to use the password by changing the line with the `AllowNoPassword` setting:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```